# Process Migration on android mobile devices

Tags: android, operating-system, process-migration

I have to get access to process control block of a running process (any app etc), transfer its code, data as well as system data from that android mobile device to another. So that that process can run on 2nd device from the same point at which it was left at 1st one.
My question is whether it is possible to see or copy PCB of running process for this purpose?
Is there any way i can migrate a running process from one android mobile device to another, if that app/process is not present there at all.
How to run an application without installing it (due to memory reasons or other) by receiving it from another device on which that application is installed, so that it can be run just for once or launching that time?
I hope i put my question clearly. Please be kind to answer it at the core level.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One sincerely hopes that nothing of what you list here is possible, for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well Process migration is very much possible, so yes you can do it.
Now about how you can do it. One way is using checkpointing. The logic is pretty simple. You create a checkpoint image or file of the process in your device and migrate it to another device where you wish to restart it.
Theoretically it sounds simple but there are various issues in checkpointing itself. My bet will be you look into some checkpointing  frameworks and see if you can incorporate them in mobile environment.

For reference look into DMTP (http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/) or BLCR since they are the most known and worked ones.

Bestties for your solution.